# Showing JList in an Applet

Tags: java, jlist

OK so whenever I open up a new appelt window with my code... the JList does not show UNTIL I click on it... how do i make it so all values appear when i start the applet?

thanks.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class inventory extends JApplet implements MouseListener {

    public static String newline;
    public static JList list;
    int gold = 123;

    public void init() {

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("Hatchet");
        arr.add("Sword");
        arr.add("Shield");
        arr.add(gold + " Gold");
        System.out.println("You have " + arr.size() + " items in your inventory.");
        showInventory(arr);

        list = new JList(arr.toArray());

        add(list);

        list.addMouseListener(this);

        list.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void showInventory(ArrayList<String> theList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(theList.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Object index = list.getSelectedValue();
        System.out.println("You have selected: " + index);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: +1 For including an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

rather than

```
list.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `list.setVisible(true);` before `list.addMouseListener(this);`. Apart from that, nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: Nope - still invisible till I click on it. :(

Comment: +1 This didn't turn out to be the problem, but it's a useful thing to look at when constructing a GUI.